# EventGrid subscription validation fails for LogicApp with AAD auth

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I have a LogicApp that is setup to use openAuthenticationPolicies and I want to connect it to the EventGrid. But either the subscription validation fails or the event delivery fails.

- If I use the LogicApp url **without** the signature, the validation fails (IMHO it should succeed):

```
"destination": {
    "endpointType": "WebHook",
    "properties": {
      "endpointUrl": "[replace(listCallbackUrl(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Logic/workflows/', variables('LogicAppName')), '/triggers/manual'), '2016-06-01').value,concat('&sig=',uriComponent(listCallbackUrl(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Logic/workflows/', variables('LogicAppName')), '/triggers/manual'), '2016-06-01').queries.sig)),'')]",
      "azureActiveDirectoryTenantId": "[parameters('Tenant')]",
      "azureActiveDirectoryApplicationIdOrUri": "[parameters('Audience')]"
    }
  }
```

- If I use the LogicApp url **with** the signature, the subscription validation succeeds, but delivering the events fails (which is expected, because you cannot specify a signature and use a OAuth token at the same time)

```
"destination": {
    "endpointType": "WebHook",
    "properties": {
      "endpointUrl": "[listCallbackUrl(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Logic/workflows/', variables('LogicAppName')), '/triggers/manual'), '2016-06-01').value]",
      "azureActiveDirectoryTenantId": "[parameters('Tenant')]",
      "azureActiveDirectoryApplicationIdOrUri": "[parameters('Audience')]"
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to get the validation to succeed and still use AAD authentication for the LogicApp?

(We use EventGrid Domains, should that make any difference).

Answer (score 0):

To use AAD authentication for webhook, follow this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/secure-webhook-delivery#configure-the-event-subscription-by-using-an-azure-ad-application) which will help to configure the event subscription by using an Azure AD application.

- I have created a logic app and configured logic app url as webhook to connect event grid.
- With out signature and complete URL, I have also faced the validation issue even AAD authentication is enabled.
  [image]
- As mentioned in above document, you can configure event subscription through AD application.
- As I don't have required permissions to move further, I cannot proceed further.
- First you need to connect to AD using tenant id. Then run the mentioned script by passing objectid and writerappid.
- If all the configurations are properly done, event grid passes Azure AD bearer token to webhook.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already did this. The problem is the validation doesn't work, even if AAD auth is setup correctly. The bearer token EventGrid sends is correct, which I checked by sending it to requestbin and also by allowing all tokens in the LogicApp (by just checking the iss claim). What exactly happens and goes wrong cannot be seen, because MS does some magic for validating LogicApps behind the scenes.

Comment: Try to check if any logs are captured in azure log analytics also suggesting you to raise a support request with Micrsoft.